# search for most friendly software partner for my Voice Recorder

Tags: audio, editing

I got this Olympus WS-750M Voice Recorder. It's really handy, and I'm getting addicted to it.

What I need to match it, is a software tool, which can easily:

1. Manage recording files
2. Cut head/tail of recordings [intelligently if possible]
3. Remove silent segment in talks [also intelligently if possible]
4. Increase S/N ratio

Freeware is most welcome, others are also fine.

Answer (score 1):

You need some kind of software recording system. For straightforward tasks like this I generally use [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/), which is free. At its core it's a wave editor, so it can handle cutting heads and tails off as well as some signal processing.

There may be better options, however, as I'm not sure how intelligently it can strip out data like you've described. I always prefer do edits like that by hand so I've not explored automating it.